# Get records of all new customers for each day from stripe and store in MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, stripe-payments

I am required to get the records of all the customers in a day from Stripe and store the records in the MySQL database table. I am able to fetch the records from Stripe and can store them in the table too. However, I want the task to be automatic and get the task done at a specific time in a day. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use an `Event` - [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) and [creating an event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html)

Comment: Is it possible with MySQL event scheduler or will it require other libraries?

Comment: If you need to fetch the data from an external third party then perhaps you need to use [CRON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)

Comment: Actually, I have to fetch data from Stripe API and store the data in a database table

Answer (score 0):

Are you open to the idea of implementing a simple application that Stripe can send webhook events to? If so, you can listen to the `customer.created` event. This way you can add a new record in your database as soon as a Customer is created.

If not, use the `List all Customers` API and supply the `created` parameter: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list#list_customers-created but this will be slightly more tedious as you'll need to paginate, since you can only retrieve 100 `Customers` per API call. To paginate, supply the `starting_after` and `ending_before` parameters. You'll also need to configure your cronjob to run at the timing that you desire.